# Downgrading Transmission

Tags: downgrade, transmission

I am registered in one of the private torrent sites and according to the site rules, some torrent clients are allowed, others are banned.

They happen to recommend the torrent client [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com) version `1.93`, but my system has the version `2.51`, is there any way I can downgrade to `1.93`?

Comment: You should complain at their forums that they use outdated clients.

Comment: @Rinzwind it is something technical....has something to do with the torrents....it is a private torrent site

Answer (score 1):

you can try over here. Remove first your actual version of transmission.
http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid-updates/transmission

Comment: Have you actually tested it before suggesting?

Comment: then what after the download

Answer (score 1):

To downgrade any package to desired version we got a command like

```
sudo apt-get install <pkg name = version here >
```

Comment: @jokerdino , Thanks . I was posted from mobile .